# apache rewrite rule set for "whitelist or catchall" in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

On the dev version of a LAMP site (Apache 2.4 on Debian 8.5), my Apache rewrite rules implement a "whitelist then catch-all" concept.
Specifically, images from `images/`, stylesheets from `css/`, javascript from `/js`, and a few named files are served directly as static files, and *all other requests* go to index.php.

The rule-set is in  the `<VirtualHost` block in the .conf file for this site:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^(/index\.php|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)$"
 RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/images/(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$"
 RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/css/(.*)\.css$"
 RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/js/(.*)\.js$"
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

And this works as intended. (It is based on [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377374/rewrite-all-url-to-index-php-except-whitelist) and adapted to work in the central config rather than in `.htaccess`.)

The problem is the test server (Ubuntu 16.04) has to imitate production, and production requires use of `.htaccess` instead of central configuration, and this rule-set does not work in `.htaccess`. So the question is how to get the same effect in `.htaccess`.

I turned on `AllowOverride all` in the `<Directory /srv/www/site1>` block in apache2.conf and put a `.htaccess` file in `/srv/www/site1` (which is the `DocumentRoot` value for this site). And based on [this apache doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html), removed initial slashes from the paths and filenames in the conditions. Also put `LogLevel info rewrite:trace8` in the VH definition to debug this problem.

Here is the current .htaccess:

```
 Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
 AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
 RewriteEngine on
 # RewriteBase "/"
 # AccepthPathInfo on
 RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^(robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|css\/styles\.css)$"
 RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^index\.php"
 RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^css/(.*)\.css$"
 RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^images/(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$"
 RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^js/(.*)\.js$"
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

And getting http 500.  Apache error log shows it's looping the rules until it hits a redirect limit, and creating a bad path like "index.php/index.php/index.php/..."

I've found a very large number of pages about URL rewriting but few are helpful on this.

EDIT: Solved by w3dk - thank you!  Applied the solution below and corrected my misspelling of "AcceptPathInfo", then it works.

Comment: With or without initial slashes, it gets the same result as mentioned, HTTP 500 with an endless loop and accumulating path + filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^(/index\.php|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)$"
> RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/images/(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$"
> RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/css/(.*)\.css$"
> RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/js/(.*)\.js$"
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
> ```

The format of your initial directives are OK for `.htaccess` as well. However, in `.htaccess` you will need an additional condition to prevent a rewrite loop after rewriting to `index.php`.

> ```
> RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^index\.php"
> ```

I can see you've tried to do this in your second code block, however, the value of `REQUEST_URI` is the same whether you are coding directly in the server config or in `.htaccess` - it still begins with a slash. So, the above *negated* condition would always be true (like all the other conditions in the second block) and so the `RewriteRule` is *always* processed.

However, you could just add another `RewriteRule` to the start of your first code block:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
```

So, put all together, this becomes:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]

RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^(/index\.php|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)$"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/images/(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/css/(.*)\.css$"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/js/(.*)\.js$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

> ```
> # AccepthPathInfo on
> ```

And `AcceptPathInfo` will need to be enabled if it isn't already.

Comment: This seems very encouraging, but I'm not clear on what the .htaccess will look like, exactly.  The new rewrite rule, then the conditions and the original rule?

Comment: Yes. I've updated my answer with a complete example. Note that the conditions (`RewriteCond`) and the final `RewriteRule` are really 1 statement/rule. The `RewriteCond` directives apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows.

Comment: Just wondering... have you considered just making an exception for files that "exist", rather than listing specific file patterns?

Comment: It still gives the 500 error with looping.  I'm starting to wonder whether something more basic is wrong, that the same rules behave differently on this server?

Comment: One purpose of the rules is to avoid serving a file merely because it's present and requested - it must also be on the whitelist.  This prevents the client retrieving non-whitelisted files or finding out about the real directory structure. Otherwise something like Apache's FallbackResource would suffice.

Comment: Yes, fair enough with the whitelist. As to the 500 error... try removing the start-of-string anchor on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. So, `RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]` becomes `RewriteRule index\.php - [L]`. And make sure the browser cache is cleared (although this really shouldn't be a cache problem).

Comment: Ah, just seen your edit - glad it now works!